# Desrialzing JSON in spring boot, where a field is the combination of two fields

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a controller with the following signiture:

```
public HttpEntity<RepresentationModel> confirmRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody RegistrationRequest request{}
```

the RegistrationRequest Json looks like this

```
{
//other fields
"countryCode":"44",
"mobileNumber": "07545878096"
}
```

I am trying to write a custom deserializer for this json

My mobileNumber class looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MobileNumber {
  @JsonProperty("mobilePhoneNumber")
  @JsonAlias("mobileNumber")
  String number;
  @JsonProperty(value = "countryCode", defaultValue = "44")
  String countryCode;
}
```

and a request object like so:

```
public class RegistrationRequest {
//other fields
  @JsonDeserialize(using = MobileNumberDeserializer.class)
  @MobileNumberValidator
  private final MobileNumber mobilePhoneNumber;

}
```

where the MobileNumberDeserializer looks like this:

```
public class ContactNumberDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MobileNumber> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected ContactNumberDeserializer() {
    super(MobileNumber.class);
  }


  @Override
  public MobileNumber deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException {

    JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    String mobileNumber = "";
    if (node.has("mobilePhoneNumber")) {
      mobileNumber = node.get("mobilePhoneNumber").asText();
    } else if (node.has("phoneNumber")) {
      mobileNumber = node.get("phoneNumber").asText();
    } else if (node.has("mobileNumber")) {
      mobileNumber = node.get("mobileNumber").asText();
    }
    String countryCode = node.get("countryCode").asText();

    return new MobileNumber(mobileNumber, countryCode);

  }
```

when the ContactNumberDeserializer is invoked by the controller,`jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);` it's just the `mobilePhoneNumber` node and cant access `countryCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick check if `ContactNumber` and `MobileNumber` are the same classes.

Ideally it should be

```
public class ContactNumberDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MobileNumber {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad yes they are.

Answer (score 0):

In your MobileNumber class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MobileNumber {
  @JsonProperty("mobilePhoneNumber")
  @JsonAlias("mobileNumber")
  String number;
  @JsonProperty("countryCode")
  String countryCode = "44";
}
```

Update JsonProperty annotation like above for countryCode. Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this has the same issue, the parser is only invoked on the mobileNumbr and not the country code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `ContactNumberDeserializer`. If you wrote your class `MobileNumber` it would simply work.